# How do I reference the containing class from a Google Maps event using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dojo, closures, dom-events

I'm doing some work converting a legacy project that uses Google Maps API v2 to v3.

There's a Dojo class that looks like this:

```
dojo.declare
(
    "MyNamespace.MapControl",
    null,
    {
        constructor: function() {
            var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
            this._map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {});
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this._map, "idle", this.map_load);
        },

        map_load: function() {
            this.onLoad();
        },

        onLoad: function () { }
    }
);
```

The issue is that, when the map_load function is called, the context of *this* is the Google Map rather than the class.

I tried creating a local variable *self* within the class and using

```
_self = this;
```

inside the constructor but the variable doesn't have the onLoad function. This is the code using that:

```
dojo.declare
(
    "MyNamespace.MapControl",
    null,
    {
        _self: null,      

        constructor: function() {
            var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
            this._map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {});
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this._map, "idle", this.map_load);

            _self = this;
        },

        map_load: function() {
            _self.onLoad(); // fails as onLoad is undefined
        },

        onLoad: function () { }
    }
);
```

Is there a way within Dojo to be able to get a reference to the parent class within the *map_load* function or is there an alternate way of hooking this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dojo.hitch(/*Object*/ scope, /*Function|String*/ method)`:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this._map, "idle", dojo.hitch(this, "map_load"));
```

For more information see http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/lang#hitch